# Find PMF when X and Y are two discrete Independent random variables

Tags: probability, random-variable, independence, discrete-distributions

Let X and Y be two independent discrete random variables with PMFs

$$\begin{equation} P_X(k)=P_Y(k)= \begin{cases}\frac{1}{5}, & \text{for}\ x= 1,2,3,4,5 \\\ 
0, & \text{otherwise} 
\end{cases}\end{equation}$$

Define Z= X-Y. Find the PMF of Z.

**My answer with working:**

$R_X= R_Y= (1,2,3,4,5)$ and $R_Z= (-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4 )$ where R⇒ Range

$P_Z(z)= P(Z=z)$

$P_Z(z)=P(Y=X-z)$

$P_Z(z)=\displaystyle\sum_{x=1}^5 P(Y=X-z)|X=x)P_X(x)$

$P_Z(z)=\frac15\displaystyle\sum_{x=1}^5 P(Y= X-z|X=x)$

$P_Z(z) = \frac15\displaystyle\sum_{x=1}^5P(Y=x-z|X=x)$

$P_Z(z)= \frac15\displaystyle\sum_{x=1}^5 P(Y=x-z)$

$P_Z(z)=\frac{1}{25}\displaystyle\sum_{x=1}^5 N(x-z \in R_Y)$ Is this expression correctly stated?

My working is as follows:

$\begin{equation}P_Z(z)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{25},& \text{for}\ z=-4 \\
\frac{2}{25}, & \text{for} \ z=-3 \\
\frac{3}{25}, & \text{for} \ z= -2\\ 
\frac{4}{25}, & \text{for} \ z=-1 \\
\frac{5}{25}, & \text{for} \ z= 0 \\
\frac{4}{25}, & \text{for} \ z= 1 \\
\frac{3}{25}, & \text{for} \ z=2 \\
\frac{2}{25}, & \text{for} \ z=3 \\
\frac{1}{25}, & \text{for} \ z= 4. \end{cases}\end{equation}$

Comment: Looks good. I would add one line between $P_Z(z)=\frac15\sum P(Y=X-z\mid X=x)$ and $P_Z(z)=\frac15\sum P(Y=x-z)$ which would be $P_Z(z)=\frac15\sum P(Y=x-z\mid X=x)$. That makes clear on a neat way that the next result is justified by independence (which you did not mention).

Comment: Because $X-Y$ has the same distribution as $X+Y-6,$ many of [our threads on the distributions of sums of dice](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=sum+dice+dist*+is%3Aanswer+score%3A5) will answer this one.